# Error when extracting tweets from twitter using r

Tags: r

I have started using R. I keep getting this error when I am trying to run this code:

```
PBunting <- userTimeline('@PeterBuntingMP',n=10000, since='2016-02-35', until='2016-11-28')
```

> Error in tw_from_response(out, ...) :    unused argument (until =
>   "2016-11-28")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the `userTimeline` function in the `twitteR` package, then you are getting this error because that function does not have an argument name starting with `until`:

```
userTimeline(user, n=20, maxID=NULL, sinceID=NULL, includeRts=FALSE, 
  excludeReplies=FALSE, ...)
```

Comment: as a side-note, `twitteR` is being [deprecated](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR#deprecation), and the `rtweet` should be used instead

Comment: Had no idea there was a better package to use. Thanks

Comment: I'm having another issue in finding sufficient documentation and examples of the the code in the rtweet package